# How to execute the part of table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, pointers, indexing

How to execute a part of table in MySQL?

Example: a table contains 5 million records. 4.5 million records were already executed, so 0.5  million records only need to be execute. Is there any possibility to a pointer? How to do it as much as faster? In this case, how to use Index effectively?

Comment: what do you mean by 'execute'?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try BETWEEN in my sql as

```
update table set field = 'xyz' where id BETWEEN startValue AND endValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update only the rows that have not been executed already by adding a `where` clause to your `update` statement that selects only the relevant rows. Like that

```
update your_table
set your_column = 'new_value'
where your_column = 'old_value'
```